# No encuentra el archivo db_connect.php al incluir el archivo

Tags: php

Éste es el mensaje de error:

> include(): Failed opening 'mro_inventory_system/project/db_connect.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in

Es lanzado en la sección de inicio de sesión. No me deja iniciar sesión con usuarios registrados dentro de la base de datos.

Parece que la ruta es el problema principal, pero veo que si declaro correctamente la ruta hasta el archivo final, que es la conexión a la base de datos.

¿Qué solución podría haber?

Dejo mis archivos PHP aquí para que los revisen, por favor.

Esto pasa solamente cuando alojo el proyecto, pero en local funciona correctamente.

Ruta de `login.php`:

[image: Captura de pantalla con la ruta]

Ruta de `db_connect.php`:

[image: Captura de pantalla con la ruta]

Contenido de `db_connect.php`:

```
<?php 
//Initializes MySQLi
$conn = mysqli_init(); 

mysqli_ssl_set($conn,NULL,NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL);

//Establish the connection
mysqli_real_connect($conn, 'invbddf.mysql.database.azure.com', 'admin', 'pass', 
'inventory', 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);

//If connection failed, show the error
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  die('Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Contenido de `login.php`:

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);  
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);  
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ?>
    <?php
    include('project/db_connect.php');
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
      <title>Login | MRO-System</title>
    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION['login_id']))
    header("location: https://invbddf.azurewebsites.net/mro_inventory_system/project/");
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya que ambos archivos están en el mismo directorio no necesitas indicar un subdirectorio en el `include`.

El código quedaría así:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);  
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);  
ini_set('display_errors',1);
include 'db_connect.php';
/* ... */
```

Además, recuerda que `include` es una construcción del lenguaje, al igual que `echo`, por lo que no necesitas usar paréntesis.

Y, por último, te recomiendo hacer uso de `require_once` en lugar de `include` para que la ejecución de tu guion finalice si no es capaz de abrir el archivo que debe incluir:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);  
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);  
ini_set('display_errors',1);
require_once 'db_connect.php';
/* ... */
```

Tras el comentario dejado en la respuesta y releer con detenimiento la pregunta veo que el origen del problema del funcionamiento de sesiones no tiene relación con el mensaje de error que parece el tema principal de la pregunta.

No te funcionan las sesiones porque no has usado `session_start()` en ningún momento. Debes hacer un comienzo de sesiones ANTES de cualquier uso de las variables `$_SESSION` y ANTES de enviar cualquier dato al navegador.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['login_id'])) {
    header("Location: https://invbddf.azurewebsites.net/mro_inventory_system/project/");
}
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);  
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);  
ini_set('display_errors',1);
include 'db_connect.php';
/* ... */
```

Comment: Cuando solamente pongo db_connect en el include me tira la conexion y dice que la variable es inespereda, pero si la dejo como la tengo si me funciona el diseno y todo pero no me deja logear usuarios

Comment: No entiendo lo que significa lo que me dices. ¿Qué variable dice el error que es inesperada? ¿En qué línea te lanza el error? ¿Podrías darme más detalles? Si es necesario edita tu pregunta para agregar nueva o más información.

Comment: cuando pongo tu codigo, esto me sale 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$conn" in /home/site/wwwroot/mro_inventory_system/project/db_connect.php on line 3

Comment: ¿Podrías compartirme el archivo `db_connect.php` (borrando las credenciales de acceso a MySQL) en algún alojamiento como Dropbox, OneDrive, Google Drive, Mega, etc? Me temo que no es un problema de inclusión de código, si no que hay algo mal en el contenido del archivo.

Comment: Por cierto, hice una edición a mi respuesta con una nueva mejora para tu código para solucionar el tema de las sesiones.

Comment: db_connect.php

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HHA8W9fH3ND6RCnnj7OS9T3i_UGfmeIX/view

Comment: Ya me he descargado el archivo y no consigo reproducir tu problema, es decir, el mensaje "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$conn" in...".

Comment: pues si esta demasiado raro, pero vere que se puede hacer gracias de todas formas

Comment: ¿Me puedes agregar a gmail y hablar desde el chat de allí? En el correo para validar el acceso al archivo tienes mi dirección.